# Using DLLImport to import a class

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I have an class in dll:
For example:

```
namespace foo {
   public class baa {
      /* ... */
  }
}
```

how can I imports the `baa` class from dll? it is possible?

```
[DllImport(DllName)]
public extern ?? foo() ??
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language is this?  With parentheses in the class name, it's not a commonly used one.

Comment: Ow,sorry. It is C#. the parentheses was an digitation error.

Comment: You don't need DllImport to use a .NET assembly... it's only needed when you want to use an unmanaged DLL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not going to work. Unmanaged DLLs export a `C` interface, not a `C++` one. And for managed DLLs (C# or C++/CLI) you simply don't need DllImport.

Only functions that are imported into a static class I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

`DllImport` is used only when you want to invoke unmanaged functions from an unmanaged library (like one written in C++).

When you have a managed .NET assembly you simply add it as reference to your project and use it.

So assuming you have a .NET class library containing the following class:

```
namespace foo {
   public class baa {
      /* ... */
  }
}
```

and then you have some other project that needs to use this assembly you go to the References node in the Solution Explorer and Add Reference to the given assembly. Then you bring the namespace into scope:

```
using foo;
```

and instantiate the class:

```
baa b = new baa();
... use the b instance here
```

Comment: My problem is that I have two dll with same names(not written by me). it is causing the conflicts. there another way to do this?

In Form1 I do reference to foo.dll and the fooAPI namespace, in form2 I try do reference to foo.dll(with different content).

Comment: it looks like a scenario bad... but I really need use it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a standard C++ export mechanism that only works with C++. You can't import it from C# directly. There are workarounds, like exporting a managed type from a MC++ assembly, use a separate managed wrapper, using COM and a type library or something like that, but you can't use the same import/export mechanism C++ applications use.

Comment: What is a standard C++ export mechanism?  I don't see any C++ here, don't see `declspec(dllexport)`, and `declspec` is not standard.

Comment: Well I assumed that's what he was talking about... I mean you kinda _hope_ that's what he was talking about.