# Unable to find an entry point named 'JoinString' in DLL 'Dll.dll'. in C#

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I create a dll in c# as you can see with this method:

```
namespace Dll
{
    public class Check
    {

        public string JoinString(string fristName, string Lastname)
        {

            return fristName + " " + Lastname;
        }
    }
}
```

I build this DLL and i want to use it in another application `DLLImport` as you can see here :

```
 [DllImport("Dll.dll", EntryPoint = "JoinString")]
    public static extern string JoinString (string fristName, string Lastname);
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = JoinString("aaa", "bbbb");

        MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());


    }
```

But i get this error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication3.exe

Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'JoinString' in DLL 'Dll.dll'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MSDN:

> **DllImportAttribute**: Indicates that the attributed method is exposed by an unmanaged dynamic-link library (DLL) as a static entry point.

Your DLL namespace seems to be written in C# which is managed code. This would result in a managed dll. You should, instead, add a reference to the dll project or utilize nuget to install your dll into other projects.

Comment: I have to to use it DLL import .So how can i change to unmanaged  code?

Comment: C# is entirely managed code. You would have to write this library in C++ or C to use the DllImportAttirbute. See the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043545/using-dllimport-to-import-a-class

There seems to be a workaround, but I've never had a need to do this and wouldn't be able to provide a reliable answer. What's the reason behind you having to use DllImport?

Comment: Because my dll is changed every weeks .so with the dllimport i just can replace the new dll.

Comment: You just replace the DLL in place and it will get used. Also, no need to use nuget for your own dll, just add a reference to the project or raw dll.

Comment: This could also be solved by using MEF or Reflection. That way, you can load up the assembly, regardless of if it has changed, and utilize it as long as it still uses a shared interface.

Comment: As long as you aren't strongly naming your assembly then you just replace with a newer version, and provided the class exists in the namespace and methods are all backward compatible everything will work. MEF or Reflection is definitely overkill here.

Comment: I often wonder why people ask questions but then ignore the answers. Thus answer explains that DllImport is used to link to unmanaged DLLs but you have a managed DLL. There are two obvious solutions to resolve the mismatch.